# MySQL: Adding parent row only if children are found (with LIKE, same table)

Tags: mysql, parent, children, relation

I have table like this:

```html
id   |    type      |    parent   |   alias
----------------------------------------------
1    |    Type1     |    0        |   animals,fauna
2    |    Subtype11 |    1        |   cat
3    |    Subtype12 |    1        |   goat
4    |    Subtype13 |    1        |   bird,owl
5    |    Type2     |    0        |
6    |    Type3     |    0        |
7    |    Subtype31 |    6        |   type2 for example,other aliasname
8    |    Subtype32 |    6        |
```

This table is used for live-search hint system and it's simple parent-child relation - no more levels.

I'm using simple query:

```
SELECT id,type FROM table_name WHERE type LIKE '%something%' OR alias LIKE '%something%'
```

it's working as i expected, but i need to extend that. I need to receive not single children row(s) only, but also their parents.

Eg.
if i'm looking for:

```
(...) WHERE type LIKE '%cat%' OR alias LIKE '%cat%' OR type LIKE '%goat%' OR alias LIKE '%goat%'
```

i need to receive not single:

```
id   |    type      |    parent   |   alias
----------------------------------------------
2    |    Subtype11 |    1        |   cat
3    |    Subtype12 |    1        |   goat
```

but also their parent (if there's any!):

```
id   |    type      |    parent   |   alias
----------------------------------------------
1    |    Type1     |    0        |   animals,fauna
2    |    Subtype11 |    1        |   cat
3    |    Subtype12 |    1        |   goat
```

Exactly like above because i'll be checking later if parent=0 to mark that row as group of children.

There's one more trick - i can search by parents too, so eg.:

```
(...) WHERE type LIKE '%Type2%' OR alias LIKE '%Type2%'
```

should return:

```
id   |    type      |    parent   |   alias
----------------------------------------------
5    |    Type2     |    0        |
6    |    Type3     |    0        |
7    |    Subtype31 |    6        |   type2 for example,other aliasname
```

Of course there will be about 500 rows with different types/aliases - and i need to return them always with parents.

I though it will be easy to do, but it wasn't (or just i have some "brain-damage" :D )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do left join the same table with alias name and pass your where clause based on the parent filter or child filter.

See below query without where clause:

```
select c.id, c.type,c.alias,p.id,p.type,p.alias from stack c left join stack p on(c.parent=p.id)
```

```html
+------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+---------+
| id   | type      | alias           | id   | type   | alias   |
+------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+---------+
|    2 | Subtype11 | cat             |    1 | Type1  | animals |
|    3 | Subtype12 | goat            |    1 | Type1  | animals |
|    4 | Subtype13 | bird            |    1 | Type1  | animals |
|    5 | Type2     |                 | NULL | NULL   | NULL    |
|    6 | Type3     |                 | NULL | NULL   | NULL    |
|    7 | Subtype31 | type2forexample |    6 | Type3  |         |
|    8 | Subtype32 | Type 32 example |    6 | Type3  |         |
|    1 | Type1     | animals         | NULL | NULL   | NULL    |
+------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+---------+
```

See below query with where clause on child filter :

```
select c.id, c.type,c.alias,p.id,p.type,p.alias from stack c left join stack p on(c.parent=p.id) where c.alias like '%cat%'
```

```html
+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+---------+
| id   | type      | alias | id   | type  | alias   |
+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+---------+
|    2 | Subtype11 | cat   |    1 | Type1 | animals |
+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+---------+
```

If you query below no output. Where child element missing. So, parent will not be fetched.

```
select c.id, c.type,c.alias,p.id,p.type,p.alias from stack c left join stack p on(c.parent=p.id) where c.alias like '%cow%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, perform a self join on the table from the child record to the parent record.  Add your criteria for the two records (parent/child).  Then alias the fields you wish to display as desired.

```
SELECT ch.id, ch.type, prnt.id AS parent_id, prnt.type AS parent_type
FROM   table_name AS ch
       JOIN table_name as prnt
       ON ch.parent = prnt.id
WHERE  (ch.type LIKE '%something%' OR ch.alias LIKE '%something%')
       AND  -- Or "OR" depending on what you are trying to do
       (prnt.type LIKE '%Type2%' OR prnt.alias LIKE '%Type2%');
```

Comment: I tried that way, but it didn't work on my full database - if i searched eg. '%Type2%' it has NOT found that parent (0 results).

Comment: Sorry, above comment is incomplete. This is my respond:

I tried that way, but it didn't work on my full database - if i searched eg. '%Type1%' it has NOT found that parent, if there was no matching children. 
In this table above it could work, because childrens have "type1" word in itself ("SubTYPE11").

And if i use OR, then return thant parent, but also ALL childrens of that particular parent (and it's unwanted).

But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Based on your title I figured you only wanted parents with children.  I guess I am not exactly clear on what you are trying to do.  Hopefully my post was helpful though.

Comment: I tried, but i had problem to explain my problem well + i'm week in english, so maybe you didn't understood properly. But  your post reminded me to use JOIN instead other 'nerdy tricks' :) Oh and sorru, but  i don't have enough reputation, to vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @gubs does not fully meet my assumptions, but showed me another opportunity to solve this problem. Instead of get one row with parent, i can, as suggested, set id of parent or NULL (if IT is a parent) at each row.

Now my query

```
SELECT p.id AS parent_id,p.type AS parent_type,c.id, c.type 
FROM table_name c 
  LEFT JOIN table_name p 
  ON (c.parent=p.id) 
WHERE 
  c.type LIKE '%cat%' 
OR 
  c.alias LIKE '%cat%'
```

returns me columns

```
   parent_id   |    parent_type      |    id   |   type
----------------------------------------------------------
```

so i can check if parent_id is NULL and get the name of the group from 'type' column instead of 'parent_type' column.

This answer satisfied me (it work perfect with my real DB), so i'll accept it :)

Thanks for help.

Comment: anytime. Good to know.